# Gausian blur in webgl at various sizes

Tags: webgl

Is there a way to get value of gaussian blurred image in a shader really fast in WebGL?

A code snippet would be nice.

Possibly mipmaps could help, but I dont know how to use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render your image on full-screen quad with fragment shader Gaussian blur.  It will be better if you render vertical blur and horizontal separately in 2 passes.

Comment: The link you provided is down

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice, flexible single pass Blur Shader: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdfGDH